# collision is not detecting in the same layer in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am working on unity2d .I have a game object called "gameobject1" on screen . It holds an image (named "state").  when  i drag a tree on a "gameobject1" collision is not detecting in the same layer. anybody know the issue?

Comment: Did you add those `Physics2D`s component: `Rigidbody2D` and `Collider2D`?

Comment: @ Xlander: hi i already added rigidbody 2d but my tree object is  rotating.

Comment: @ Xlander : For this i added fixed angle on rigid body.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following.

1. Go to Physics settings in Edit/Project Settings/Physics2D (because you are in 2D mode). Check whether everything is perfect in the collision matrix/triangle.
2. From script you must use OnCollisionEnter2D / OnTriggerEnter2D methods to receive collision notifications.
3. If the above two steps are correct then check how you created the Unity Project. Tat is 2D Mode or 3D Mode. Because for 2D games 2D Mode is recommended while creating new project.

Comment: its ok its al working fine ... bt do u know how polygon collider2d detects it. I have two object namely tree and state.When I drag the tree object on to the state object its show dispaly that the tree has being dragged on the stateobject.how?

Comment: You can use OnCollisionEnter2D or trigger method which is ina script and attached to gameobject. You can attach it to one object. And based on collision layer or gameobject name or tag you can know which object is collided.

Comment: When I drag a tree on a gameobject1 collision is happening continuosly in the same layer instead of once. I already added Physics2Ds component Rigidbody2D on to tree object.                                                                          http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80494/continous-collision-happening-in-unity2d/80497#80497

Comment: If you want to stop collision as and when it collides at once you can make the rididbody as Kinematic. or Don't try to move the object by adding force or manually moving it. It is colliding because the force is continuous or you are moving the object manually